# Can Julia run on SPARC Solaris?

Tags: julia

I like Linux but I have spare capacity on an enterprise class SPARC Solaris platform.  I'm just wondering if anyone has tried running Julia there before as it doesn't seem to be a supported OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Julia does not run SPARC Solaris. Supported platforms are x86 (Linux+windows+mac+FreeBSD), ARM and Power8-LE. A SPARC port would not be *too* difficult, but would need to be done by someone who cares about that platform, and has access to relevant hardware. Unfortunately, that does not describe most of the current developers and contributors.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet but future interest might also come from wanting to use Julia on FPGAs, in combination with open softcores such as Leon -- a SPARC architecture already supported by LLVM.